# .NET MVC app, weird exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I changed nothing, but now there is a lot of exceptions what i don't know why to throw. I deleted the contents of the temporary folders, the errors still exists. It looks like, a permission went wrong, but i've not still found out where.

[image: The exceptions]

Comment: Have you changed anything in your file structure? Or logged on your computer with a different user?  Have you tried to "clean solution"?

Comment: Are you administrator of your system?

Comment: @Zaphod No, but i tried to copy (and clean) the entire solution to another place, but it didn't helped. I have one user, this is the admin. If i run the visual studio as administrator, the situation is the same like above, but the first two exceptions doesn't throw.

Comment: It's hard to say what the issue could be. Is your solution in TFS? Does your event log provide any clues?

Comment: Reinstall Visual Studio and .NET! Burn it all!

Comment: @Sippy I've almost done it, but before i tried on a different machine, and there is the same errors, so the problems digged somewhere in the solution.

Comment: have you tried to remove the references to the missing packages and then reinstall them? (via nuget?)

Answer (score 0):

Endlessly, i loaded backups, and merged the files with the current state, and figured out that, i've done a stupid renaming mistake, what corrupted the route configuration... With the fixed routing, everything works fine.

[image]